# Why is there a pattern on Microsoft Office menu bar?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, themes

[ Moved from Stack Overflow ]

My partner is seeing four irregular blotches on the right side of the menu bar in Excel, Word, and PowerPoint. They go away if the window is shrunk to a narrow enough size for them not to display in their entirety, but reappear if it is expanded.

This [screenshot](http://www13.zippyshare.com/v/9Wwk4Blb/file.html) shows what it looks like. On the File page, the 4th blotch is hidden behind the green navigation bar, whereas in edit it shows up on the green all the way across.

This is not affecting functioning, but it's odd enough that we're concerned it may be malware-related (though searches for that have revealed nothing). I'm not seeing the behavior on my system. We're both running on Windows 10.

Absent an explanation, it would be helpful to know if anyone else is seeing this.

Comment: The screenshot is now a dead link.  So this is a picture guessing question without the picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing is the Office background. You can change it in any Office program by clicking the `File` tab, then `Account` and then choosing a background.

Comment: I apparently can't change the question text. If someone who can would make it "Why is there a pattern on Microsoft Office menu bar?" it'll be more likely that someone else who runs into this can find it.